# VideoJS custom player theme on iphone

Tags: iphone, html5-video, video.js

Is there any way to customize VideoJS (v. 5) HTML5 player on iPhone?

We created custom elements on top of the player and also custom controls using the `createEl()` method. Everything looks fine on desktop, mobile (android) and tablets (android and ipad) but when it comes to iPhone the player is falling back to HTML default controls and custom elements are not displayed (see below images).

The player on Android:

[image: The player on Android]

The player on iOS:

[image: The player on iOS]

There is also a portion of code in `createEl()` method in video.js which tells us something about breaking on iPhone.

```js
// insert the tag as the first child of the player element
// then manually add it to the children array so that this.addChild
// will work properly for other components
//
// Breaks iPhone, fixed in HTML5 setup.
Dom.insertElFirst(tag, el);
this.children_.unshift(tag);

this.el_ = el;

return el;
```

Any solution for this issue?

Comment: That screenshot is not of iOS. iOS's native video element does not look like that.

Comment: Yes, I know. I used the Chrome inspector to take these print screens,  simulating an Android device and an iPhone. I tested also on physical devices and the result is the same and, as you mentioned, the default HTML5 player on iOS looks different. The conclusion is that based on browser headers, the player is rendered different.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: You can not (today, maybe on future) if you are playing videos using the Safari browser on iPhone.

Mobile Safari on the iPhone does not allow videos to play inline, they must always go fullscreen. The iPad will play them inline, though I do not believe they can have overlapping content.

If you want to play inline, you would need to build your own iOS application which has a UIWebView. UIWebView has a property, allowsInlineMediaPlayback, which can be set to YES. When using this on the iPhone, you can then use custom HTML for a video tag which sets the webkit-playsinline attribute.

Check here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH3-SW20

**iOS Note: On iOS, full-screen videos can only display the default controls**.

Comment: I know that when we start the project there was no support for inline video playing on iOS, but starting with iOS 10, there is hope.

[Starting in iOS 10, WebKit relaxes its inline and autoplay policies](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/)

Also, our client noticed that on "Washington post" the articles containing videos have custom controls and other elements as you can see [here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-switch/wp/2017/02/05/uber-twitter-netflix-and-other-tech-giants-to-call-travel-ban-unlawful-in-rare-coordinated-legal-action/?utm_term=.5750df2664ff)

Comment: @Adrian. Nice feature. But I understood that you can play videos inline, not in fullscreen, but the controls will be there and I do not believe that you can "overlay" them. If you check the source, you will see that you can create a video element, and play it, but it was not appended to the body. The code creates a canvas element and painted the video's frames on itself. So, you can simulate a video player, because you can overlay that canvas attached to the body adding your own controls over it.

Comment: @Adrian. I found a code that may help you. This enables iOS 10's playsinline attribute on iOS 8 and iOS 9 (almost a polyfill) but it has no controls, no user interaction. Check here: https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video